# How do I use _DEBUG_ERROR in my own code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Inside the `<vector>` header, there is code like this:

```
_DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterator not dereferencable");
_SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
```

Which halts the program with a message and gives the programmer a chance to debug the code.

For a little toy project, I want to use `_DEBUG_ERROR` myself. It is defined in `<xutility>`.

However, when I include `<xutility>` and try to use `_DEBUG_ERROR`, I get the following error:

```
error C3861: "_Debug_message": identifier not found.
```

But `_Debug_message` *is* defined inside `<xutility>`, in line 28! Why does the compiler complain?

Also, is there another (maybe even somewhat portable?) way to halt the program for debugging?

Comment: whats wrong with assert/abort?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Those don't give such a nice error message window, but I guess I could live with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% certain but I'm fairly sure it's actually `std::_Debug_message`. And PlasmaHH is right: `assert()` is the normal solution. You can write `assert(!"message")` to get a custom message. (Note the !)

Comment: Thanks, a simple `using std::_Debug_message;` fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ASSERT` or `_ASSERT` macro for assert-and-debug. Or, you can craft your own assert-macro. Use the definition of `_ASSERT` (taken from `crtdbg.h`):

```
#define _ASSERT_EXPR(expr, msg) \
        (void) ((!!(expr)) || \
                (1 != _CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__, NULL, L"%s", msg)) || \
                (_CrtDbgBreak(), 0))
```

The important function here is [_CrtDbgReportW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hyw4sy7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which will display the assertion dialog-box having three standard buttons (Abort, Retry and Ignore). Depending on return value you can then call other functions. In the macro given above, function `_CrtDbgBreak` is called when user hits 'Retry' button (which causes function to return 1, see MSDN).

You may write to a log file, display to debug output window (using `OutputDebugString`), or do things you may like.